# Best Practice on .NET BCL Method

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, class

Need some suggesstion on the following case

I have a Child Method that initializes a Service Client Instance after setting the binding information and the endpoint information programmatically. The variable that holds the instance is defined at the class level and the child method just sets it to a new instance.
During a code review session a developer suggested that we pass the instance as a argument for the child method and return the argument back to the main method. Whis is the best way to do this

```
private void InstantiateClient()
{
    //do some configurations on bindings and endpoint 
    _ClassLevelInstanceClient = new ServiceClient(bindingInfo, endpointInfo);
}
```

or

```
private ServiceClient InstantiateClient(ServiceClient myClientInstance)
{
    //do some configurations on bindings and endpoint
    myClientInstance = new ServiceClient(bindingInfo, endpointInfo);
    return myClientInstance;
}
```

Comment: Well what was this developers reasoning for doing so?

Comment: There is no "best way".  You should generally not have parameters that you don't use.  Assuming (because the first example works) that you are not using `myClientInstance` in the section labeled `//do some configurations on bindings and endpoint`, there is no compelling reason to pass the ServiceClient in as a parameter.  Whether you return it or just set an instance field is up to you.  Makes very little difference.

Comment: Your question about which is best cannot be answered without showing more code and providing more context.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys! The other developer's comments were based on the statement that it is easier to maintain when the code is split into smaller methods. The Class has high number of LOC, the developers argument was that once can be confused with the object state in such a huge class, and instantiating objects by calling the method as required would be easier code to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess we need more knowledge of your application in order to provide a proper solution. Best way would be to find a reason from the concerned developer about the comment. I, personally, do not agree with it. Although here's little something I would probably do.

In the parent/calling method:

```
using(ServiceClient client = InstantiateClient()){
//Make service call here
}
```

In the child method,

```
private ServiceClient InstantiateClient()
{
    //do some configurations on bindings and endpoint 
    return new ServiceClient(bindingInfo, endpointInfo);
}
```

Again, if it makes sense in your application, I would make InstantiateClient to be a generic method as follows:

```
private ClientBase<T> InstantiateClient(){
// create and return specific client here
}
```